# Can't create a vue cli app with node-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-sass

I'm new to vue.js, and I'm trying to create a vue cli app, I already have vue, node and node-sass installed on my computer. But when I'm trying to create a cli app using node-sass like this:

```
vue create vue-cli-app
```

And when I have to pick a CSS pre-processor, I only have these options:

```
 Sass/SCSS (with dart-sass) 
 Less 
 Stylus
```

node-sass isn't an option !

Any idea how to fix it ?
Thanks !

I tried to restart VSCode, or my laptop and it didn't work !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install it on your project to use it.

```
npm install -D sass-loader node-sass
```

More here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass

Comment: I also tried and still didn't work

Comment: I think your question is Vue specific , I would try other approaches like using vite: https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project . Because I don't know if Vue removed the node-sass option.